# Using Beautifulsoup and regex to traverse javascript in page

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm fetching webpages with a bunch of javascript on it, and I'm interested in parsing through the javascript portion of the pages for certain relevant info.  Right now I have the following code in Python/BeautifulSoup/regex:

```
scriptResults = soup('script',{'type' : 'text/javascript'})
```

which yields an array of scripts, of which I can use a for loop to search for text I'd like:

```
for script in scriptResults:
    for block in script:
        if *patterniwant* in block:
            **extract pattern from line using regex**
```

(Text in asterisks is pseudocode, of course.)

I was wondering if there was a better way for me to just use regex to find the pattern in the soup itself, searching only through the scripts themselves?  My implementation works, but it just seems really clunky so I wanted something more elegant and/or efficient and/or Pythonic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I lot of website have client side data in JSON format. I that case I would suggest to extract JSON part from JavaScirpt code and parse it using Python's json modules (e.g. json.json.loads ). As a result you will get standard dictionary object.

Another option is to check with your browser what sort of AJAX requests application makes. Quite often it also returns structured data in JSON.

I would also check if page has any structured data already available (e.g. OpenGraph, microformats, RDFa, RSS feeds). A lot of web sites include this to improve pages SEO and make it better integrating with social network sharing.

Comment: What would be a good resource to check out re: scraping data from JS code?  I'm a stats person who has a passing knowledge of basic CS (I learned just enough so I can aggregate data for my research, and enough so I don't blindly hammer a server) so I'm less familiar about the intricacies of collecting data from a MVC site framework other than from the page source.  I checked microformats and sadly the sites don't use it, so I'm resorting to options I know will work, but presumably aren't best practices.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that scrapping structured data from plain HTML is not trivial task. That's what makes Semantic Web progress exciting http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Main_Page